# Handling very big Matrix mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, performance, mariadb

I have a python project where I analyse some datasets on matrix models that represents relations between different nodes in a net.

The data from the matrix must be persisted for further statistical historical processing. If it's possible I should use MySQL since I have previous dependencies on the project.

My problem is that the amount of registers could be over 7 billions for 5 hours of execution with a size of 300Mb aprox.

Which would be the best database model I should use to be able to perform reasonably efficient queries into the DDBB?

Does anyone have any experience on similar situations?

Comment: Do you really need a database for this? It's highly uneffective. Just save files on disk. If you still want this, save text files to a database as blobs.

Comment: I want to query the data to make statistical processing. For example i want to know which nodes and where they are, who are talking to a particular node

Comment: Then take note of the HDF5 format. It was developed for big, complex, multilayer data and has libraries and packages for many languages, including python. It has also visualization tools: https://support.hdfgroup.org/products/hdf5_tools/SWSummarybyName.htm

Comment: How can you squeeze 7,000,000,000 number into 300,000,000 bytes?  Is each smaller than 1 byte?

Comment: True story, the data is much bigger than 300Mb. Not sure how much.
I look the HFF5 format, thanks.